# How to open a dialog related to a panel position or a specific control position

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

**When click the button i want to open a dialog and this dialog position will be
at center panel** 


I try this block of code but its not work:

```
        FormDialog f = new FormDialog();
        f.Parent = panel1;
        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
```

[image: Open Dialog]

Comment: parent refers to the parent window, not control

Comment: you would have to calculate the position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the position manually. First you can obtain the position of center of `panel` on the screen and then place your form at this coordinates.

```
Form2 f = new Form2();
f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
Point panelCenterPosition = panel1.PointToScreen(new Point(panel1.Width / 2, panel1.Height / 2));
f.SetDesktopLocation(panelCenterPosition.X - f.Width/2, panelCenterPosition.Y - f.Height/2);
f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Why the extra calculations at `SetDesktopLocation`? Shouldn't showing at `panelCenterPosition` suffice? Why subtracting from `f.Width/2`. I tested your answer and mine. Yours doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo Excta calcualtions to place the center of form at the center of panel. In your answer you place topleft corner of form at the center of panel. Can't say what are you missing, do you have an error?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I changed the coordinate to screen coordinates. The panel's Left and Top are calculated from the container's edge whereas the SetDesktopLocation expects screen coordinates.

The parent property of a form points at the parent form not the panel in this case. In order to show the form in a specific location however you can do the following:

```
frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
Point p = panel1.PointToScreen(new Point(panel1.Width / 2, panel1.Height / 2));
frm.SetDesktopLocation(p.X, p.Y);
frm.Show(this);
```

Comment: @DmitryDovgopoly Oops. Fixed.